# Shortcut for making a new window in Safari

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

Whenever I use the new window shortcut in Safari, it creates a new tab instead of a new window. This most likely happens due to my having chosen the setting `System Preferences > Dock > Prefer tabs when opening documents: > Always` checked.

However, strangely enough, clicking on the menu bar item `File > New Window` seems to create a new window normally – not a new tab.

Is it possible to create a new tab with the shortcut?

Comment: What version of Safari and OS X/macOS are you using?

Comment: Whoops, macOS Sierra 10.12.3 running Safari 10.0.3

Comment: Presumably Sierra, considering that pref

Comment: In macOS Sierra 10.12.3, by default the keyboard shortcut to open a new window in most apps is **⌘N**, however when one changes the default setting in **System Preferences** > **Dock** > **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** from **In Full Screen Only** to **Always**, the **New Window** keyboard shortcut is changed to **⌥⌘N**. Under those circumstances, are you saying that in Safari when you press the System assigned keyboard shortcut for **New Window** it opens a new Tab instead on a new Window?

Comment: Wow! So I changed the **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** setting to **Always**. Then I realized in Safari the shortcut was **⌥⌘N**. I was confused, but decided to change the shortcut to **⌘N** in **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts**. That's what led me to the problem above. Looks like I can't make the shortcut **⌘N** and retain the **New Window** functionality. If you write your comment as an answer to the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In macOS Sierra 10.12.3, by default the keyboard shortcut to open a new window in most apps is **⌘N**, however when one changes the default setting in **System Preferences** > **Dock** > **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** from **In Full Screen Only** to **Always** the **New Window** keyboard shortcut is changed to **⌥⌘N**.